# Can you give me a pro-Kremlin news source?

Tags: russian-federation, political-system, society

As a daily academic exercise, I read news articles on the same topic from multiple news agencies with a different political orientation. I'd like to add a pro-Kremlin news agency; with a preference for the most pro-Kremlin biased one. Are there any suggestions?

So far, my current curriculum includes the following agencies, in no particular order:

- De Volkskrant; semi-populist, relatively in-depth, center-right
  Dutch newspaper
- Trouw; in-depth with a birds-eye view, leftist Dutch newspaper
- Foreign Affairs, in-depth solution-supported essayist American news
  journal
- The Economist, briefing type British newspaper
- Bloomberg.com, American briefing type news agency with an emphasis on
  financial news
- Al Jazeera, international news from the Gulf-states

  [the intention of the subjective trivializing descriptions above is to make a distinction between the agencies]

Aside from my search for a pro-Kremlin news agency, are there any suggestions on how to further diversify and enhance my news curriculum?

Comment: De Volkskrant isn't center-right, it's center-left ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Volkskrant))

Comment: Can you explain to me why it's center-left according to your Wikipedia article source? When it comes to acknowledging things in the left-right spectrum, I find it hard myself to give a supporting argument; so I go for gut-feeling for lack of a good understanding of the concept.

Comment: [The Dutch source](https://thesis.eur.nl/pub/3907/thesisEDomevscek.pdf) of the Wikipedia comment stating that De Volkskrant is center-left is 10 years old, so I guess that's too old to still be valid. However you may find the discussion between left and right media in the thesis interesting. De Volkskrant used to be left and it's my understanding that they have become more right in recent years. Truth be told I stopped reading them a few years ago so it could be that they have become more right than I perceive them to be.

Comment: if it's in no particular order, use bullet points instead of numbered points

Comment: Starting from revision #5, this became a totally different question. This invalidates all existing answers. Voting to close.

Comment: I removed the extension question about a Chinese news source. You could ask this as a new question. Extending the question to "any other region" would make the question too broad, though, because it would be hard to tell how granular you actually want to be (do you want the unique opinion of every little rebel group in Elbonia or only the twenty major ones?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All news is propaganda to promote the interests of those who own or fund (through advertising, etc.) the news outlets.  That is the bad news.  The good news is that good propaganda is **not** outright lies.  Good propaganda is a carefully selected part of the truth to promote the agenda of the funder.

To see anything resembling the whole truth about an issue, you need to find news sources funded by sides opposing each other on that issue and then compare their propaganda.

Below are a few news sources not yet mentioned by previous posters, with their funding source shown in the parentheses.

- [BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/)  (British government)
- [Cuban News Agency](http://www.cubanews.acn.cu/)  (Cuban government)
- [Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw.com/)  (German government)
- [People's Daily](http://en.people.cn/) (Chinese government)
- [South African Government News Agency](http://www.sanews.gov.za/)  (Government of S. Africa)
- [teleSUR TV](http://www.telesurtv.net/english/index.html)  (several left-leaning/populist governments in Latin and Central America)
- [Voice of America](http://www.voanews.com/)  (US government)
- [Xinhua](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/home.htm)  (Chinese government)

Comment: Hmm, why the down-vote?  OP also wanted to "further diversify and enhance his news curriculum", besides looking for pro-Kremlin news sources.

Comment: Do you have a reasonable mechanism of detemining all relevant actors concerning a specific issue? I mean, most news outlets are in the private sector. Only sticking to the government-owned ones, seems rather narrow.

Comment: The OP ask about pro-Kremlin sources, you didn't put any of them. I don't see the BBC as a pro-Kremlin.

Comment: @nelruk - the OP also asked for a suggestion on how to "diversify and enhance" his news curriculum.  That is what I tried to address.  The pro-Kremlin sources (RT, Sputnik, TASS) have been covered by others.

Comment: As a suggestion @ebhh2001 you could cover news agency (not cited in any part) that has good relations with, say, Russia Today (RT). As a latin american, I can assure for example that TeleSUR has good relations with RT and give a support in this part of the world.

Comment: @MusséRedi - it really depends on the issue. For some issues, all actors have at least some ability to spread their propaganda through the media.  For other issues, one actor may have unlimited access to media and other actor(s) have none whatsoever (usually due to lack of funds).

Comment: @nelruk - I agree that teleSUR, which BTW is on my list, would fall in the pro-Kremlin category.

Answer (score 14):

[Russia Today](http://rt.com) is a news network funded directly by the Russian government. You don't get anything with a stronger pro-Kremlin bias than them.

Comment: I sometimes have a look at their content. You'll also find some conspiracy theories and other off-the-wall stuff.

Comment: You do: http://tass.ru/en , http://sputniknews.com, and others, are more strongly pro-Kremlin.

Answer (score 7):

RT has been mentioned, but another worth nothing is [Sputnik International](http://sputniknews.com/).  Without whom I would never have learned that not only does [National Walrus Day](https://www.facebook.com/SputnikNews/photos/pcb.10152818216416181/10152818214276181/?type=3) exist, but it is November 24th.  Their editorial bias is pretty much the Kremlin line, only they're aimed at an international audience.  I was sad when they came to be, because they replaced [RIA Novosti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIA_Novosti); which was decidedly more independent.

If you want a weird one, [Al-Manar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Manar) is Hezbollah's TV channel.  [Press TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_TV) is Iran's state international.  [Al Arabiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Arabiya) is Saudi's international news.

[France 24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_24) is good, and also decidedly French.  [Haaretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haaretz) is Israel's left wing daily.  [NHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHK_World) is Japan's state international, [CCTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCTV_News) is China's state international.

Hope they are of use!

Comment: Also the [Syrian Arab News Agency](http://sana.sy/en/), and if you want to get even more crazy (it's possible), the (North) [Korean Central News Agency](http://www.kcna.co.jp/index-e.htm).

Comment: I've been upstaged.  I thought Al-Manar was biased enough :( North Korea is so obvious now!  Ah, good references!

Comment: I noticed that both RT and Sputniknews are relatively fast when it comes to security breaking news.

Comment: I find it funny, that China's state TV outlet is called CCTV